# How to solve tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, object-detection

I am trying to train an object detection model using the CenterNet MobileNetV2 FPN 512x512 architecture provided by TensorFlow Model Zoo.

**I am only interested in object detection and not keypoints.**

Here is my `pipeline.config`:

```
model {
  center_net {
    num_classes: 2
    feature_extractor {
      type: "mobilenet_v2_fpn_sep_conv"
    }
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 512
        max_dimension: 512
        pad_to_max_dimension: true
      }
    }
    use_depthwise: true
    object_detection_task {
      task_loss_weight: 1.0
      offset_loss_weight: 1.0
      scale_loss_weight: 0.1
      localization_loss {
        l1_localization_loss {
        }
      }
    }
    object_center_params {
      object_center_loss_weight: 1.0
      classification_loss {
        penalty_reduced_logistic_focal_loss {
          alpha: 2.0
          beta: 4.0
        }
      }
      min_box_overlap_iou: 0.7
      max_box_predictions: 20
    }
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 8
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 0
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 2
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 1
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 4
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 3
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 6
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 5
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 8
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 7
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 10
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 9
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 12
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 11
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 14
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 13
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 16
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 15
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_patch_gaussian {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
      max_aspect_ratio: 1.7
      random_coef: 0.25
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_hue {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_contrast {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_saturation {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_brightness {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_absolute_pad_image {
      max_height_padding: 200
      max_width_padding: 200
      pad_color: 0.0
      pad_color: 0.0
      pad_color: 0.0
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    adam_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 5e-3
          total_steps: 300000
          warmup_learning_rate: 1e-4
          warmup_steps: 5000
        }
      }
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  num_steps: 1000
  max_number_of_boxes: 1
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  use_bfloat16: false
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "annotations/train.record"
  }
  filenames_shuffle_buffer_size: 256
  num_keypoints: 17
}
eval_config {
  num_visualizations: 10
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  min_score_threshold: 0.20000000298023224
  max_num_boxes_to_visualize: 20
  batch_size: 1
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "annotations/test.record"
  }
  num_keypoints: 17
}
```

When I run the command to train the model:

```
python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/model_2 --pipeline_config_path=models/model_2/pipeline.config
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\literally everything\code\projects\Side Scroller Game with Gesture Detection\Tensorflow\workspace\iteration_3\model_main_tf2.py", line 114, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\literally everything\code\projects\Side Scroller Game with Gesture Detection\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 36, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\literally everything\code\projects\Side Scroller Game with Gesture Detection\env\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 308, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\literally everything\code\projects\Side Scroller Game with Gesture Detection\env\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 254, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\literally everything\code\projects\Side Scroller Game with Gesture Detection\Tensorflow\workspace\iteration_3\model_main_tf2.py", line 105, in main
    model_lib_v2.train_loop(
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\literally everything\code\projects\Side Scroller Game with Gesture Detection\env\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 685, in train_loop
    losses_dict = _dist_train_step(train_input_iter)
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\literally everything\code\projects\Side Scroller Game with Gesture Detection\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\literally everything\code\projects\Side Scroller Game with Gesture Detection\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

indices[0] = 0 is not in [0, 0)
         [[{{node GatherV2_8}}]]
         [[MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard]]
         [[RemoteCall]]
         [[while/body/_1/IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference__dist_train_step_40356]
```

I would appreciate any help regarding this problem. If you need extra information about the project configuration, do tell me.

Thank you in advance.